# linux + match IP ADDRESS with 3 octets or with 4 octets

Tags: linux, grep, solaris, regular-expression, ksh

how to match IP address with 4 octets or with 3 octets in one command?

target - match  xxx.xxx.xxx or xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ( syntax should fit for Linux and Solaris )

how to merge the following commands in one command ?

```
 echo $IP_ADDRESS  | grep  '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}'
 echo $IP_ADDRESS  | grep  '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}'
```

I also try this ( But its not work )

```
        echo $IP_ADDRESS | egrep "[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}|[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if expr ".$IP_ADDRESS" : '\(\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\)\{3,4\}$' > /dev/null 
 then echo match
 else echo no match
 fi
```

You can't use `grep` here because `grep` is used to match lines, not strings. You can't use `echo` either as it does substitutions on its arguments. You can't leave variables unquoted either as otherwise filename generation and word splitting occurs.

If you want to find the lines that match that pattern in an input file, then that's where you want to use `grep`. Like:

```
 grep -Ex '[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1.3}){2,3}' < input.file
```

Would report all the lines that consist exactly (`-x` option) in a 3 or 4 up to 3-digit decimal numbers.

If you want to extract all the 3 or 4 up-to-3-digit-decimal-numbers IP addresses in a text file, then probably the best option would be to resort to `perl`:

```
perl -lne 'print for grep /^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){2,3}$/, /[\d.]+/g'
```

Would output:

```
111.222.333
1.2.3.4
```

For an input like:

```
foo 1.1234.2.3 1.2 1.2.3.4.5 111.222.333 bar1.2.3.4@
```

Though you could also do:

```
tr -cs 0-9. '[\n*]' < input.file |
  grep -Ex '[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1.3}){2,3}'
```

Comment: is it possible to use your syntax after PIPE LINE for example cat file | "your syntax"   , so I will catch all relevant IP's

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
echo $IP_ADDRESS | grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){1,2})'
```

or using the named sets:

```
echo $IP_ADDRESS | grep -Eo '([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}(\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}){1,2})'
```

#### Examples

```
# 4 octets
$ echo '10.10.0.1' | grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){1,2})'
10.10.0.1

# 3 octets
$ echo '10.10.0' | grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){1,2})'
10.10.0

# 2 octets
$ echo '10.10' | grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){1,2})'
$
```

**NOTE:** These will match all expressions from 0.0.0.0 to 999.999.999.999

Comment: its not match the IP with 3 octets as this example: echo 172.17.200 | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'

Comment: its work for 4 octets but not for 3 octets : IP_ADDRESS=192.2.2 ; echo $IP_ADDRESS | egrep '[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}'

Comment: another part /usr/xpg4/bin/grep: illegal option -- o ( on solaris )

Comment: `-o` is a GNU extension so typically won't work on Solaris. Your solution would say that `foobar\n1.2.3` matches, so would `foo.2.3.4.5.6.bar`

Comment: Yup, I should've asked what version of Solaris you're using. My experience has been newer ones were including GNU versions of grep.

Comment: Do you need to just detect if a 3 or 4 octet is present or do you need to grab it for some use later on? I would use @StephaneChazelas, answer if you're just detecting. His answer could be reformulated into a single one-liner if that's what you're after.

Comment: I need to detect , but I prefer to detect it after PIPE LINE for example .... |  'check if match IP '